# Should the availability of digital purchases be marked as OnlineOnly?

Tags: ecommerce, schema.org, download

Since the [`ItemAvailability`](http://schema.org/ItemAvailability) seems to deal primarily with physical objects, I wanted to make sure that [`OnlineOnly`](http://schema.org/OnlineOnly) could be applied to digital downloads. Or, should digital downloads not have an `ItemAvailability`?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific schema standard, or a protocol, in what context are you talking about. Please consider adding more information as an edit to your question so that we can better understand and provide you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s not relevant if it’s a physical item or a digital item.

An example that makes clear that the difference shouldn’t matter when deciding if and how [`availability`](http://schema.org/availability) should be used: You could sell concert tickets, from your online shop *and* from your retail store, in digital form *and* in paper form (from both places).

[`OnlineOnly`](http://schema.org/OnlineOnly) means that the item can only be purchased from the web shop, while [`InStoreOnly`](http://schema.org/InStoreOnly) is for the opposite case. Both can be used for digital and/or physical items. (I guess they are intended for cases where an organization has both, a web shop and a physical store, but using them in cases where only one is available shouldn’t hurt.)

If you want to convey that it’s a digital item (for download), you could use the [`availableDeliveryMethod`](http://schema.org/availableDeliveryMethod) property with the value

```
http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload
```

So for a product that can be downloaded after purchase from your web shop, it could look like:

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Offer">
  <link property="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  <link property="availability" href="http://schema.org/OnlineOnly" />
  <link property="availableDeliveryMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload" />
</div>
```